# Check if all patterns are in file

Tags: grep

Say I have a `patterns.txt` and want to check if every one of those patterns is present in some file.

I could do something like:

```
for pattern in $(cat patterns.txt); do 
  if ! grep -q "$pattern" file.txt; then
    echo "Error: missing pattern $pattern"
  fi
done
echo "All patterns found"
```

but this is inefficient as it has to re-scan `file.txt` for each pattern (and is not as simple if instead of a file we're looking for patterns in a stream coming from a pipe that may be large, e.g.).

Is there a way to have `grep` (or some other tool) check if *all* the patterns are present?

Comment: When you say "is present", do you mean whether the actual _pattern_ is present, or if the pattern matches?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file.txt | awk '
    NR == FNR {seen[$0] = 0; next} 
    {for (p in seen) if ($0 ~ p) seen[p]++} 
    END {
        for (p in seen) 
            if (seen[p] == 0) {
                missing++
                print "missing pattern", p
            } 
        if (missing == 0) print "all found"
        exit missing
    }
' patterns.txt -
```

Replace the `cat` command with any pipeline that produces text.

Answer (score 0):

This might work well:

```bsh
sort -u patterns.txt > sorted_patterns.txt # only once
diff -sq <(grep -o -f sorted_patterns.txt file.txt | sort -u) sorted_patterns.txt
```

If you have fixed strings instead of patterns, use `-F`. This makes `grep` a lot faster!

You could [also use `cmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900538/fastest-way-to-tell-if-two-files-have-the-same-contents-in-unix-linux) instead of `diff -s`. That might be a bit faster, but won't be able to show what is missing.

---

Output if not all patterns have been found:

```
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ
```

or if all patterns have been found:

```
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

Leave out `-q` to know **what** is missing.

```
2a3
> missing_word
```

Answer (score 0):

with `grep` and PCRE extension and also using power of the `printf` command; you would do something like:

```
<infile grep -qzP "(?s)$(printf "(?=.*?%s)" $(<pattern.txt))" &&
 echo 'all matched' ||
 echo 'one or more pattern(s) does not found'
```

if all patterns (in **any order**) found in input file *infile* then text *`all matched`* will goes to output; otherwise text *`one or more pattern(s) does not found`* will echo.

this will act pattern as a matched pattern like `pat[01]` will match both `pat0`&`pat1`; to match exact pattern say `pat[01]` literally change `printf` control modifier from `%s` to `%q` which that will escape special characters.

```
<infile grep -qzP "(?s)$(printf "(?=.*?%q)" $(<pattern.txt))" &&
 echo 'all matched' ||
 echo 'one or more pattern(s) does not found'
```